# Eternal installation little errors, how to avoid?

Tags: postgresql, installation

I am trying to install PostgreSQL v9.10 into a fresh Ubuntu 16 LTS... All standard procedures

1. As say at https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

   1.1.  create `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`

   1.2. `wget --..  apt-key add  ... apt-get update`
2. `apt install postgresql`

### The eternal error messages, how to avoid it?

```
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
Setting up postgresql-10 (10.1-1.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/ at /usr/sbin/pam_getenv line 78.

...

... Success. You can now start the database server using:

    /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l logfile start

Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz to provide /usr/share/man/man1/postmaster.1.gz (postmaster.1.gz) in auto mode
Setting up postgresql (10+189.pgdg16.04+1) ...
...
```

So, the "eternal errors" (every install, perhaps since v9.0) is

- The repeated many lines *"Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by `<-- HERE in m/(?<!\\)\${ <-- HERE ([^}]+)}/` at ..."*
- The red line *"10  main    5432 down   postgres ..."*

How to **say to may boss *"look this messages, all is perfect, do not worry!"*?**

Can I fix something before? Can I, after installation, do something to demonstrate that there are nothing, PostgreSQL is 100% **reliable**?

---

See also [ubuntu/bug/1545904](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/1545904): there are somethong in the other side, a kind of "official excuses" of the PostgreSQL-team, expressing  that we must ignore the messages?

Comment: They are only warning messages. Try `apt-get -q update` or `apt-get -qq update` to reduce noise. But if it works, why do you care?

Comment: Hi @Bohemian, I have been living together this "bug" for years, no problem... But for "my boss" (really professional and *audited installation*) I need to proof that is all ok... To "reduce noise" is not a reliable procedure... Why in ~9 yers (and now with v10.1) no body fixed the bug??  Perhaps there are an "official excuses" page where the PostgreSQL-team say that we must ignore the messages.

Comment: it's open source... attach a formal complaint to your next licence fee instalment.